# Rpy2 Installation issue, windows 7

Tags: python, r, installation, rpy2

I am trying to find solution for my problem, so far not with success.

I am trying to install latest Rpy2 version on my computer. I already have all required programs (R 2.15.1 and 2.7 Python) installed. I am installing Rpy2 (rpy2-2.3.0) trough cmd with command

`python setup.py build install`

I am getting this traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "setup.py", line 441, in
>
> [os.path.join('doc', 'source', 'rpy2_logo.png')])],
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
>
> dist.run_commands()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
>
> self.run_command(cmd)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
>
> cmd_obj.>run()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
>
> self.run_command('build')
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
>
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
>
> cmd_obj.run()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
>
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
>
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 971, in run_command
>
> cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
>
> self.finalize_options()
>
> File "setup.py", line 152, in finalize_options
>
> config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
>
> File "setup.py", line 312, in get_rconfig
>
> rc = RConfig.from_string(rconfig, allow_empty = allow_empty)
>
> File "setup.py", line 272, in from_string
>
> - '\nin string\n' + string)
>
> ValueError: Invalid substring
>
> in string

The same error I get when trying to install with

`easy_install rpy2`

UPDATE: now the same error shows on the other pc (64bit)

Thanks for help! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gave up on the `rpy` package. I will recommend **PypeR** package it is faster, easy to install (easy_install) and enjoyable to use! http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PypeR/

Comment: Hi, how is PypeR comparing to rpy2 now, for windows? (2017/08)

Comment: Hi, I've stuck with PypeR package and didn't used rpy2 at all, however PypeR  should be inferior to rpy2 in terms of capabilities. Sheer simplicity of PypeR kept me away from more robust rpy2. Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630441/how-do-rpy2-pyrserve-and-pyper-compare  I think these packages did not changed much in last few years. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I just get rpy2 to run on Windows. It's actually not that hard.