# Getting error in installing rpy2 on windows

Tags: rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 package and getting following error both with

```
C:\python27>easy_install rpy2

Searching for rpy2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Reading http://rpy.sourceforge.net
Best match: rpy2 2.3.3
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.3.3.tar.gz#md5=6cd95eb70645577cb53198ef0a32395e
Processing rpy2-2.3.3.tar.gz
Running rpy2-2.3.3\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\chetan~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-wfxip9\rpy2-2.3.3\egg-di
st-tmp-rrezfb
"C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-28~1.0\bin\R" CMD config --ldflags
Invalid substring

in string

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:921: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for ex
ception
  raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
error: Setup script exited with Problem while running `"C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-28~1.0\bin\R" CMD config --ldflags`
```

And when I try pip this is what I get

```
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin>pip install rpy2
```

Downloading/unpacking rpy2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package rpy2

```
"C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-28~1.0\bin\R" CMD config --ldflags
Invalid substring

in string

Problem while running `"C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-28~1.0\bin\R" CMD config --ldflags`
```

Comment: `conda install rpy2` just works in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few days on this too... then I stumbled upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), where a link is given: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

On this page you can find (amongst other useful things) a pre-compiled version of rpy2 for Windows, and for different versions of Python. It apparently only works for R 2.15.3, I did not try it with other versions.

Answer (score 0):

## Recently had to attempt to build this from source.  Got the rpy2-2.2.2 version so I can use with with Python 2.6.6 on Oracle Linux.

The solution to getting this to work was to fix a couple of things in the setup.py script.

First, allow get_rconfig() to allow empty strings.  If there was a way to flag this, it wasn't obvious to me:

```
    config = RConfig()
    for about in ('--ldflags', '--cppflags',
                  'LAPACK_LIBS', 'BLAS_LIBS'):
        #config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
        config += get_rconfig(r_home, about, allow_empty = True)
```

Secondly, fix a bug with the dropthrough in RConfig.from_string, where it was referencing a non-existent variable:

```
            elif rconfig_m is None:
                if allow_empty:
                #if allow_empty and (rconfig == ''):
                    print(cmd + '\nreturned an empty string.\n')
```

This then allows the R CMD config loops to get parsed and the empty cases (which you will probably encounter if your R build was not built as a shared library) and I am able to complete the cycle with

python setup.py build install

Comment: I have had a similar problems dealing with Python 2.6 and rpy2.
Eventually, I found that 2.3.10 appears to be the last version of rpy2 that is compatible with Python2.6. So all that needs to be done is `sudo pip install rpy2==2.3.10` .

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for posting, though why are you checking for `rconfig_m == ''` when the previous check is `if rconfig_m is None`

Comment: Good question @name_masked.  As you notice, I was doing a code hack and probably did a blind replacement of rconfig to rconfig_m.  You're correct in that an empty string does not equate to None.  Feel free to get some edit credit by fixing the above post.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> `"C:\PROGRA~2\R\R-28~1.0\bin\R" CMD config --ldflags`

is probably caused by the absence of unix like tools in windows. (you might also have had an error like

> 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I finally got it to work on windows 7 by installing Rtools and mingw compiler and changing the setup.py and unixccompiler.py file. See [rpy2 install on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7)

Also the error

> %load_ext rmagic
>
> RuntimeError("Unable to locate R.dll within %s" % RHOME)

is caused by rpy2 not able to find R.dll correctly in the code. You can add R_HOME environment variable as eg C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2 the outside folder (for details see the link).

Hope this helps..