# Python rpy2 Install

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I installed RPY2 and when I try to import this I get the following error.

```
Unable to determine R version from the registry. Trying another method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy.py", line 53, in <module>
    RHOME = rpy_tools.get_R_HOME()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy_tools.py", line 57, in get_R_HOME
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't execute the R interpreter.\n"
RuntimeError: Couldn't execute the R interpreter.
Check whether R is in the execution path.
```

I am pretty sure I need to add C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin to a path for python to know to use R, but I am not sure how, or what path to add it to.

I can get to the were you add it to the paths but past that I am lost. Could someone please help.

Comment: rpy has been deprecated for many years. Try rpy2.

Comment: When I try to easy install rpy2. I get error: Setup script exited with Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.

Comment: This answer may help you out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7