# Installing rpy2 -- Variable Error

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2. I have installed R, and rpy2. I try to import rpy2.robjects as robjects.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to locate R.dll within %s" % R_HOME)
RuntimeError: Unable to locate R.dll within C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\
```

I have created R_HOME as  C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\64 in my environment variables
. There is a R.dll in this location what am I doing wrong why wont this work?

Comment: I'm unsure of the implications in python, but R doesn't like spaces in the path when building packages etc.

Comment: I tried taking the space out that didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1`, `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin`, and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64` to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Are you [Gohlke's binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)?

Among various combinations, R_HOME of 
c:\Progra~1\R\R-3.0.3\

and

c:/program files/r/r-3.0.3

worked for me. Looks like either it doesn't like the  or the `\` or both.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably caused by the R_HOME variable pointing to x64. Use as mentioned c:\Progra~1\R\R-3.0.3\  in the R_HOME variable. See [rpy2 install on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7/28288996)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out this is NOT the correct path to put in R_HOME:

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\64

instead use:

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\

Substituting whichever version number you have installed for R-3.0.2.

I looked in the rpy2 source and saw it searched R_HOME with bin appended and lib appended, so you don't need it in R_HOME.