# IPython notebook and rmagic/rpy2: cannot find module ri2py (OSX 10.8.5, python 2.7, R 3.1)

Tags: r, macos, ipython, rpy2

I'm trying to use the rmagic extension for the IPython notebook, using Python 2.7.6 via Enthought Canopy.

When I try the following example:

```
import numpy as np  
import pylab  
X = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])  
Y = np.array([3,5,4,6,7])  
pylab.scatter(X, Y)

%Rpush X Y  
%R lm(Y~X)$coef
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-7-96dff2c70ba0> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().magic(u'Rpush X Y')
----> 2 get_ipython().magic(u'R lm(Y~X)$coef')
…  

/Users/hrob/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/rmagic.pyc in eval(self, line)  
    212             res = ro.r("withVisible({%s})" % line)  
    213             value = res[0] #value (R object)  
--> 214             visible = ro.conversion.ri2py(res[1])[0] #visible (boolean)  
    215         except (ri.RRuntimeError, ValueError) as exception:  
    216             warning_or_other_msg = self.flush() # otherwise next return seems to have copy of error  

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ri2py'
```

I can't find anyone else who's had the same problem and don't know enough to solve it myself. There is no definition for ri2py in conversion.py though.
I initially had installed Anaconda and was running python notebook through that, with exactly the same results.

rpy2 (version 2.4.0) installed successfully but when I test it I get 1 expected failure as follows:

```
python -m 'rpy2.robjects.tests.__init__'  
…  
testNewWithTranslation (testFunction.SignatureTranslatedFunctionTestCase) ... expected failure
```

I don't know if that's related.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and how I might fix it? Are the versions of python, R, etc. that I'm using compatible or do I need to re-install/update something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you using `%load_ext rmagic`?

If so, try using `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` instead.

This is one of the [new features](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/changes.html?highlight=ri2py#new-features) in version 2.4.0.

Comment: Yes, I was, and it's now working with `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: With `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, I get `ImportError: No module named 'rpy2.ipython  # for later IPython versions, e'`. Is there something else I need to do when installing `rpy2`?