# how to resolve import rpy2 robjects error

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, rpy2

I am importing rpy2.robjects and receiving following error on executing python code in spyder IDE :
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda33\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py", line 37, in _dlopen_rlib
rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)

OSError: cannot load library 'C:\ProgramData\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e

I have R installed and R_HOME, R_USER env variables set, also it workes till import rpy2, error occurs on importing rpy2.robjects.

Using Anaconda3-2020.02 having python version 3.7.6 and rpy2 version 3.3.4

python -m rpy2.situation yields following error :
[image]

Env variables value :
[image]

any help with this will be appreciated.

i have tried to run same on pycharm by creating virtual env using native python 3.8 interpreter and pip installing rpy2 on it, getting same error with that too.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863535/rpy2-cannot-find-r-dll ?

Comment: it suggests to use 32bit R , have already tried it, doesn't work. possibly the error is in  openrlib.py when it tries 'rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)' the lib_path here is not the same as here R.dll resides on my machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)