# Building python external module using cygwin

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cygwin

I am trying to build a python (2.7) module using cygwin:

```
D:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build -c cygwin
```

However I get the following error:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'mod' extension
D:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe -mcygwin -mdll -O -Wall -ID:\Python27\include -ID:\Python27\PC -c my_mod.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\my_mod.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mcygwin'
error: command 'D:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7

Comment: Do not mix cygwin tools and compilers with a not cygwin python.