# Problems with utils.install_packages() in RPy2 for Installing R Packages via Python Interface

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm looking in integrate my code in R into Python with rpy2, but have been running into a lot of trouble getting started with the tutorials. Initially, I couldn't get anything to work, but I found this ([rpy2 install on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7)) and was able to get the basics working. It seemed kind of sketchy but I'm not going to complain if it works.

Starting with some basic tutorials I found online, I ended up with the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

package_names=('afex','emmeans')
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
packnames_to_install = [x for x in package_names if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]
if len(packnames_to_install) > 0:
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))
```

Everything works fine up until the if statemate, which returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-126-93d1ee5af75e>", line 2, in <module>
    utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))

  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

RRuntimeError: Error in (function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), contriburl = contrib.url(repos,  : 
  unable to install packages
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: did u find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`RRuntimeError` exception are originating from the embedded R. For some reason you are unable to install R packages. This could originate from permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Run python with admin privileges before calling utils.install_packages(..)