# Output from Python used by R in real time

Tags: python, r, time, synchronization, output

For some reason I'd like to use R to plot a Python output in real time.

Let's imagine a simple case like this one:

```
# Python
import random
for i in xrange(100):
    output = random.gauss(1,1)

# R
output.vector = append(output.vector, output)
plot(output.vector)
```

How can I transfer the variable `output` from Python to R in real time? I think there are two questions (or more) hidden behind this one:

1. What is the most efficient way to synchronize the two programs?
2. What is the most efficient way to transfer a value from Python to R (write on a text file?)

Comment: Have you discovered [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) yet?

Comment: The answers to the question below are very relevant to what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630441/how-do-rpy2-pyrserve-and-pyper-compare.. Personally working on Windows I have found that using PypeR was a lot easier than Rpy or Rpy2.

Comment: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/ should be useful