# Python port of R's 'relaimpo' package

Tags: python, r, linear-regression

I need to calculate Lindeman-Merenda-Gold (LMG) scores, for my regression analysis. I've found that is is available under `relaimpo` package in R-Language.

Unfortunatelly, I don't have any experience with R. I checked the internet but I couldn't find. Is there a python port of this package ? If it doesn't exist, is it possible to use that package through python somehow ?

Comment: eventually related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630441/how-do-rpy2-pyrserve-and-pyper-compare

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't reveal more details about the exact problem you want to solve, I assume you are just looking for the way of calling R code from python.

I think [rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/index.html) might be a good start point for you. Below are some possibly helpful references about using `rpy2`

- [*Calling R From Python With rpy2*](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2022/05/25/calling-r-from-python-with-rpy2/)
- [*Python -> R bridge*](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2)
- [*Calling R from Python | Magic of rpy2*](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/calling-r-from-python-magic-of-rpy2-d8cbbf991571)
- [*Rpy2 Made Easy*](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/rpy2-made-easy-d67a9c8b84c8)

**Most Importantly**: Considering you didn't touch `R` previously, I guess it would be better you read the manual of `relaimpo` before you start using `rpy2`. You can search the related documents through CRAN or other external sources, e.g.,

- [*relaimpo: Relative Importance of Regressors in Linear Models*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html)
- [*Relative Importance for Linear Regression in R: The Package relaimpo*](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v017i01)